# What is the process to define the number of rows in a php-laravel code

Tags: php, laravel

I have a database of around 500 employees. I want to search for a particular emp. But the search is only limited to one page - since one table in laravel consist of 15 rows. But i want that search to be completely applied on all the 500 emp so that i can find a particular searched name. How can i do that? any suggestions?

[image]
If you can see, the table has only 15 rows and my search is limited to only one sheet at a time. and there are abour 8-9 sheets in the bottom.
How to solve this ?

Comment: That feature is called "pagination" and there's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination) for it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel inbuilt pagination with adding some dynamic elements. I would suggest using something like [Livewire Datatables](https://rappasoft.com/docs/laravel-livewire-tables/v2/introduction). By using [Livewire](https://livewire.laravel.com/), you can add dynamic elements to your page without writing javascript.